# Postgres check if coordinates are within a range

Tags: postgresql, geometry, elixir, postgis

I have a table containing matches info. One column, called coordinates, contains a jsonb with lat lng coordinates like this:

```
{"lat": 70.852104, "lng": 7.937035}
```

Client app can filter matches, sending me a json like this one:

```
{"lat": 65.852104, "lng": 6.937035, "distance": 300}
```

I need to query all matches that are included between coordinates and distance sent by the client. Can i create a proper query without changing type of coordinates column? How to do that? Postgres version is 9.6.2.

Comment: I'm afraid you're not going to like it: The only reasonable way to deal with geo data is using the `postgis` extension. Believe me, you'll be surprised how helpful it is! The installation is pretty straightforward and you will only need to store your existing `jsonb` coordinates as `geometry` in a new column, and then use something like `ST_Distance` . If you already have `postgis` installed  and do not have the luxury of creating a new column, you can do it dynamically... let us know.

Comment: This is only tangentially related to Elixir. It's much more a postgresql question. I mean even without ecto or elixir you could (and probably should for testing) run the query directly against postgresql.  Fix the postgresql part first and then if you still have an issue with Elixir, post a separate question for that.

Comment: I'd also say this is a poorly researched question since you don't share any queries you've tried or any research you've actually done.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

Using the extension [**PostGIS**](https://postgis.net/install/) it can be achieved by means of parsing the *x* and *y* axes from the `jsonb` column and casting them to a single `geometry`

Based on this table structure ...

```
CREATE TABLE t (foo jsonb);
```

... containing these records ...

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('{"lat": 70.852104,"lng": 7.937035}');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('{"lat": 6.9647297,"lng": 50.93706}');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('{"lat": 65.852104,"lng": 6.937035}');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('{"lat": 51.964800,"lng": 7.625200}');
```

... you can calculate the distance from a given point `7.6252, 51.9648` using the following query:

```
WITH j AS (
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' ||
            CAST(foo#>'{lng}' AS TEXT) || ' ' || 
            CAST(foo#>'{lat}' AS TEXT) || ')',4326) AS geom FROM t
) SELECT ST_Distance(j.geom ,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(7.6252,51.9648),4326)) FROM j;
```

Result in degrees.

```
   st_distance    
------------------
   18.88987806884
 62.4573738133821
 13.9043440498155
                0
(4 Zeilen)
```

The **4326** at the [**ST_SetSRID**](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) and [**ST_GeomFromText**](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) stands for [**WGS84**](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/) and can be changed depending on your [**SRS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system). The Function [**ST_MakePoint**](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) expects at least two double precision values (*x* and *y*) for creating a `geometry`. [**ST_Distance**](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html), as the name suggests, calculates the distance between two geometries.